# Problem with Cal, EventAggregator, and Application.Deactivated

Tags: c#, eventaggregator, cal

I'm having an interesing problem with CAL and the event aggregator.  I am attempting to publish an event when the app is deactivated or activated (application.activated and application.deactivated).  Some of my modules have popup boxes that a I want to hide when the application loses focus.

this is a small code sample below

app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppDeactivatedEvent>().Subscribe(RunIt);

    Deactivated += (s, a) => eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppDeactivatedEvent>().Publish(EmptyPayload.Empty);
    Deactivated += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine("Deactivated - in app.xaml"); 
    Activated += (s, a) => eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppActivatedEvent>().Publish(EmptyPayload.Empty);

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Module.cs

```
ea.GetEvent<AppActivatedEvent>().Subscribe(presenter.AppDeactivated);
```

presenter

```
public void AppDeactivated(EmptyPayload empty)
{
    Console.WriteLine("App Deactivated - Module");
}
```

What happens is that when the app loses focus I get the following in the console
Deactivated - in app.xaml
When the App regains focus I get the below
App Deactivated - Module

Any ideas on why the event aggregator would wait until the app regains focus for the event to fire.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

turns out I had an issue with my event subscription. no problem, just tired eyes